# How do I create an endpoint in pyramid, and attach python code to it?

Tags: python-3.x, rest, pyramid

So I have built a application using hug, a python web framework. Now I am looking to move the system to pyramid, but pyramid is very confusing to me, even the tutorial. All that I really need for now is create endpoints (ie get: index.html, get: upload.html, post: upload) and attach python functions that I have already written to those endpoints

I have tried doing the pyramid tutorial, but even that seems confusing to me, and it seems like I am missing steps, or they were left out

Just to summarize, I am looking for a way to create a number of endpoints, both get and post, and attach python functions that I have already written to these endpoints

Comment: Please explain which tutorial you tried and what specifically you find confusing. Your question is too broad to provide a useful answer.

Comment: I tried the quick tutorial, I am a bit confused with the idea of a virtual environment, and I am confused with pyramid, specifically with creating endpoints, and with attaching code to those endpoints.

Comment: Again, please explain what exactly is confusing, in other words, what did you try, what did you expect, what did you observe?